# Matching covariant list

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, covariance

I have a base class (let us name it `Base`) and multiple extended classes and method for validation `validate` which accepts `Any`.

I would like to check if the parameter is a subclass of Base so I can call `validate` method from it and also if it is List of instances of subclass of Base to do the same.

I tried the code below, but this does not compile. Is there a simple, elegant way of doing this?

```
class Base {
  def validate(): Unit = {}
}

class Extended1 extends Base {
  override def validate(): Unit = {
    // some checks
  }
}

def validate(param: Any): Unit = {
  param match {
    case b: Base => b.validate()

    // this is not working
    case l: List[+Base] => l.foreach(_.validate())

    case _ => // do nothing
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
I can use override of methods. I have some more checks which I removed from question, and that was mistake, sorry.

So:

```
def validate(param: Any): Unit = {
  if (Option(param).isEmpty) throwMissingReqFieldException(param)
  param match {
    case b: Base => b.validate()
    case _ =>
  }
}

def validate(param: List[Any]): Unit = {
  if (Option(param).isEmpty || fieldValue.isEmpty) throwMissingReqFieldException(param)
  // here I would like to recursively call validate if possible, maybe this is the solution
  param.foreach(x => validate(x))
}
```

Comment: Firstly, there's no point using type parameters in pattern matches, because they're erased at runtime. I think you're looking for `List[_ <: Base]` though.

Comment: Not sure I get it, you mean in List case?

Comment: The moment you decided to use `Any` simple and elegant solutions went out of the window.

Comment: Yes. `case l: List[Base]` would also match a `List[String]` or anything else

Comment: It's much better to overload the method

Comment: You want a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) instead of inheritance and pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

Try approach with a type class

```
trait Validate[T] {
  def validate(t: T): Unit
}
object Validate {
  implicit def defaultValidate[T]: Validate[T] = _ => ()
  implicit val baseValidate: Validate[Base] = _.validate()
  implicit def baseListValidate[B <: Base]: Validate[List[B]] = _.foreach(_.validate())
}

def validate[T](param: T)(implicit v: Validate[T]): Unit = v.validate(param)
```

Comment: This is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely need an `Any` as a parameter, do this:

```
def validate(param: Any): Unit = {
  param match {
    case b: Base => b.validate()
    case l: List[Base] => if (list.forall(_.isInstanceOf[Base])) l.foreach(_.validate())
    case _ => // do nothing
  }
}
```

Here, the `[Base]` part is actually useless, but it tells the compiler to treat your list as a `List[Base]`. The actual check is in the if statement, where you make sure all of the objects are `Base` objects.

You could also do `l.foreach(b => if (b.isInstanceOf[Base]) validate(b))` if you don't care that the list doesn't contain only `Base`s and also could also contain `String`s or whatever

A better way to do it would be overloading, though:

```
def validate(b: Base): Unit = b.validate()
def validate(l: List[Base]): Unit = l.foreach(validate)
```

Comment: Checking that the first element is a base is not enough, you may have a `List[Any]` where the first element was a base but the others were ints for example.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez True, updating my answer

Comment: Overloading seems fine, but it won't allow me to override with List[Base] and List[Any]. I will update the question.

Comment: @Darko Try the first solution with `l.foreach(b => if (b.isInstanceOf[Base]) validate(b))` instead of the if statement

Comment: I can do ```l.foreach { case b: Base => b.validate; case _ => }```

Comment: I think this is the best solution, so far. Thanks @user.